# How do I pass a dictionary object to jinja2 where the dict.keys are the tokens are the dictionary values are what I want to display?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I am a GAE/Python newbie.  I am trying to render a jinja2 template where the template values are in a dictionary object.  I would like to do something like this:

```
some markup {{ dict['token001'] }} some more markup {{ dict['token002'] }} etc.
```

whereby token001and token002 are the values of keys in the Dictionary.

I am thinking the call would look something like:

```
template = jinja_environment.get_template(fileName.html)     
outputblob = template.render(dict)
```

Can anyone tell me how I can accomplish this?  I have over a thousand tokenized files and up to a few dozen tokens per file.  There are multiple sets of values for the same tokens in a database and logic pulls out one set of tokens and value and puts them into a dictionary and that is what I want to pass to jinja2 for rendering.

Can anyone tell me how to pass a dictionary object to jinja2 where the dictionary keys are the template tokens?

Thanks for any suggestions or pointers towards a solution.

+++++Edited question++++++
I tried the following and it appears to be working up to a point.

The tokens in the template file now look like {{tokenvals.tkn001}}

```
    tokenvals = q.fetch(999)
    tokendict = {}
    for tokenval in tokenvals:
        tokendict[tokenval.tknID] = tokenval.tknValue

    template = jinja_environment.get_template('khan-exercise.html')     
    bloboutput = template.render(tokenvals = tokendict)
```

At least I am not getting an error message up to this point.  However, when I try to save the results in the following code I get an error:

```
    f = GeneratedFiles(
        TemplateName = TemplateName
        , FileTxt = bloboutput
        , Status = 'Published'
        )
    f.put()
```

This results in an error BadValueError: Expected str, got u'

The model for the data is:

```
class GeneratedFiles(ndb.Model):
  TemplateName = ndb.StringProperty()
  FileTxt = ndb.BlobProperty()
  Status = ndb.StringProperty(default="Pending Translation")
```

One thing I noticed is that the rendered string includes \n everywhere there was a carriage return. However, the entire rendered text is as a string between apostrophes (single quotes - ').  The template file itself includes a lot of double quotes - ").  I don't think that has anything to do with it.

I have frequently seen error message: Expected str, got u' followed by the text and I never figured out what was causing it.

Any further suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean, can you give an example dictionary that you want to pass in? (also, please change your example name from `dict` to something else, because `dict` is the dictionary constructor, so it's a bit confusing to see both in there). The code that you have up there right now would just insert the values for key 'token001' and 'token002' into the output of the template.

Comment: dict is a very bad choice of variable name since it is a basic type name in python.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  dict['token001'] = 'this is the text that should be inserted for key = token001'; dict['token002'] = 'this is the text that should be inserted for key = token002' - there are up to a hundred different values for each token in a database from which they are pulled for different situations.  The typical template file can have a couple of dozen tokens.  I am open to use any structure that will work for this situation (does not have to be dictionary). Thanks for any help.

Comment: lecstor got me beyond the pure dictionary issue and now I can't get the put to work with the blob.  See edited original question.

Comment: is it the blob that is the issue? sounds like it's TemplateName. does `TemplateName = str(TemplateName)` fix it?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  If I comment out the , FileTxt = bloboutput line, it works (at least no error).  When I leave the blob statement in , the error starts with BadValueError: Expected str, got u'<!--\n    TODO: eventually, this template can replace... (everything after got u is part of the template file text).

Comment: I just found a reference that says that u'string'means unicode.  I am not sure what the implications of this are but at least I can stop wondering what the u is.

Comment: sorry, yeh, did you try the same thing with FileTxt? `FileTxt = str(bloboutput)`

Comment: hmm.. that might not be the best idea even if it does work.. > Never ever use str() on a unicode string, or unicode() on a byte string without a second argument specifying the encoding... http://blog.notdot.net/2010/07/Getting-unicode-right-in-Python

Answer (score 3):

you could also let us know what isn't working for you. Did you try the call as you thought it would look? What broke?

I think this should work..

```
some markup {{ tokens.token001 }} some more markup {{ tokens.token002 }} etc.

tokens = get_tokens_dict()
template = jinja_environment.get_template(fileName.html)     
outputblob = template.render(tokens=tokens)
```

or maybe..

```
data = { 'tokens': tokens }
outputblob = template.render(**data)
```

Comment: I think I do not really understand what you meant by the statement tokens = get_tokens_dict()?  I have the following code:
    tokenvals = q.fetch(999)
 / tokendict = {} 
 / for tokenval in tokenvals: 
 / tokendict[tokenval.tknID] = tokenval.tknValue  
 / tokenvals = tokendict()  
This results in TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable.
What am I missing?